# Integral over integrals with different measures

Tags: ct.category-theory, measure-theory

I was trying to construct a category of measurable spaces and 'nondeterministic functions' (not the usual category of measurable spaces); specifically a map $(\Omega, \Sigma)\rightarrow (\Omega', \Sigma')$ is a function $f$ from $\Omega$ to the set of all probability measures on $\Sigma'$ such that for each $\sigma'$, the function $\omega \mapsto f_\omega(\sigma')$ is measurable. The idea is that $f(\omega)$ is in $\sigma'$ with probability $f_\omega(\sigma')$. So after defining composition:
$$ (gf)_\omega(\sigma'') = \int_{\Omega'} g_{\omega'}(\sigma'')df_\omega(\omega') $$
(here the notation $\int f(x) d\mu(x)$ indicates that $\mu$ is the measure and $x$ the dummy variable),
the condition that composition is associative is equivalent to 
$$ \int_{\Omega'} \left(\int_{\Omega''}h_{\omega''}(\sigma''') dg_{\omega'}(\omega'') \right) df_\omega(\omega')= \int_{\Omega''}h_{\omega''}(\sigma''') d(gf)_\omega(\omega'')$$
Here $f : (\Omega, \Sigma) \rightarrow (\Omega', \Sigma')$, $g : (\Omega', \Sigma') \rightarrow (\Omega'', \Sigma'')$, $h : (\Omega'', \Sigma'') \rightarrow (\Omega''', \Sigma''')$, $\sigma'''\in\Sigma'''$, $\omega \in \Omega$, and the other omegas are dummy variables.
Is this known in the literature? I'm not very familiar with measure theory. I strongly suspect that it is true, because all of the other axioms have worked so far (e.g. the composition of two measures really is a measure, identities work out properly). This will probably have a longish, boringish proof involving approximation by simple functions, which I want to avoid going through if someone else has. Indeed, if someone else has proven this, perhaps the category I am considering has already been invented. Does it look familiar to anyone? Perhaps a version of the chain rule, but for integrals?

Edit: The proof of this is actually shorter than I had thought. However, the maps have already been studied; see the answer(s).

Answer (score 5):

Your maps are precisely what is called **Markov kernels** in probability. These kernels and their composition are discussed in many places. See, for instance, Section 36 from Probability theory by Bauer.

Comment: Knowing they are called "Markov kernels" allows one to find [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066105806024?np=y), in which a closely related category is discussed. The `f_\omega`'s are only required to be subprobability measures.

Comment: Of course, one can - it doesn't make much difference (for instance, one can always add an "ideal point" where all the missing probability goes).

Answer (score 2):

This is the *category of probabilistic mappings*, introduced by Lawvere in some [never published notes](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/scans/lawvere1962.pdf) from 1962. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1488) by Culbertson and Sturtz has references to most of the subsequent literature and serves as a good primer.